# How to find the "ordinal hash code" of specified sequence?

Tags: c++, .net, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have a sequence of **[-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]** and the task is to reach goal sequence of **[1,2,3,0,-1,-2,-3,-4]**. Symbol **"0"** means a gap - it could be swapped for a non-gap symbol like this:
**[-1,-2,-3,-4,1,0,2,3]**. At each manipulation with initial sequence the cost is 0 (zero). I need to know the coefficient of how close each successive sequence to the goal sequence. It might be a value on range [0.0 - 1.0] where **1.0** means the goal sequence and **0.0** means initial sequence, or it could be a hash-code value of type **INTEGER**, but this value should be less & less with each approach to the goal sequence. Any ideas how to implement that? I tried string comparison algorithms (edit distance), but they don't work for this case.

Comment: So you mean something like sum(abs(dist(elementpos, targetpos))) normalised?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But the value should go down with each approach to the goal state. I need it in Anneal Simulation search as function that generates next state, but the next state must be estimated with some value to compare with previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all numbers are unique.

Untested code ahead

```
using SumType = int64_t; // feel free to shoot yourself in the foot by using floats.
SumType PosSum(const std::vector<int>& curr, const std::vector<int>& goal) {
  SumType sum = 0;
  for(auto it = curr.begin(); it != curr.end(); ++it) {
    // if (*it != gabValue) ???
    sum += std::abs(std::distance(it, std::find(goal.begin(), goal.end(), *it));
  }
}
```

Alternative use a std::unordered_map to store goals positions, might be faster.

```
auto init = PosSum(start, goal);
if (init == 0)
  return;

...whatever

auto now = PosSum(current, goal); // slight problem as init is not guaranteed to be a global minima.

auto coeff = double(1.0) - double(now)/double(init); // which makes this [x:1] where x can be zero or negative
```

Comment: The sum is always 32

Comment: I tried for many combinations and the sum is always 32.

Comment: Sorry, dude! I was wrong, I didn't sleep well. The function changes with each combination. You were correct and I accept your answer